# Getting error org.json.JSONException: No value for status on uploading file to server

Tags: java, android

I am new to android i am working on an app where i need upload a resume to server using retrofit.. So on uploading resume i got error org.json.JSONException: No value for status on catch block of response... i am not able to find any solution for it... Can anyone help to solve this error... attaching my code with php code as well...Help me to correct it..

Api

```
@Multipart
@POST("m/interview_registration")
Call<ResponseBody> interviewRegister(@Query( "name" ) String name,
                           @Query( "mobile" ) String mobile,
                           @Query( "email" ) String email,
                           @Query( "address" ) String address,
                           @Query( "location" ) String location,
                           @Query( "exp_years" ) String exp_years ,
                           @Query( "exp_months" ) String exp_months,
                           @Query( "apply_for" ) String apply_for,
                           @Query( "last_qualification" ) String 
                           last_qualification,
                           @Part MultipartBody.Part file);
```

Upload method

```
  private void submitData(String applicantName,
                        String applicantMobileNo,
                        String applicantEmail,
                        String applicantAddress,
                        String applicantLocation,
                        String applicantDesignation,
                        String applicantExpYear,
                        String applicantExpMonth,
                        String applicantEduDetail,
                        String filePath) {

    if (NetworkUtil.isNetworkAvailable(this)) {

        submitButton.setEnabled( false );
        loader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        File file = new File(filePath);

        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), filePath);
        MultipartBody.Part fileToUpload = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("resume", file.getName(), requestBody);

        Log.e("info", applicantName + " "
                + applicantMobileNo + " "
                + applicantEmail + " "
                + applicantAddress +  " "
                + applicantLocation +  " "
                + applicantDesignation +  " "
                + applicantExpYear +  " "
                + applicantExpMonth +  " "
                + applicantEduDetail +  " "
                + fileToUpload);

        Api api = ApiClient.getClient().create( Api.class );

        Call<ResponseBody> call = api.interviewRegister(applicantName, applicantMobileNo, applicantEmail, applicantAddress, applicantLocation, applicantDesignation, applicantExpYear, applicantExpMonth, applicantEduDetail, fileToUpload);

        call.enqueue( new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                try {

                    submitButton.setEnabled( true );
                    loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    String JSON_STRING = response.body().string();
                    JSONObject jsonRootObject = new JSONObject( JSON_STRING );


                    String status = jsonRootObject.getString( "status" );
                    String message = jsonRootObject.getString( "message" );

                    if (status.equals( "1" )) {

                    } else {
                        loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        submitButton.setEnabled( true );
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    popUpDialog();
                    Log.e("CrashReport", e.getMessage());
                    // Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Error\n" + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                    submitButton.setEnabled( true );

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Failed " + t, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                submitButton.setEnabled( true );

            }
        } );
    }
    else {
        popUpDialogInternet();
    }

}
```

Php code

```
     //File Upload Code
  $file = $_FILES['resume']['tmp_name'];
  $file_name = $_FILES['resume']['name'];
  $file_size = $_FILES['resume']['size'];
  $file_type = $_FILES['resume']['type'];

   // print_r($_FILES);exit();


  if(!empty($file))
  {
    $ext = $this->getFileExtension($file_name);
    if($ext == 'pdf' || $ext == 'doc' || $ext == 'docx' || $ext == 'jpg' || $ext == 'jpeg' || $ext == 'png')
    {
      if($file_size <= 20000000)
      {

      /*  $ext = $this->getFileExtension($file_name);
    $name = time(). '.' . $ext;
    $filedest = FCPATH."/interview/" . $name;

   if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["resume"]["tmp_name"], $filedest))
    {
      $up_res['upload_status'] = 1;
      $up_res['upload_status'] = 1;

    } else {
      $up_res = 0;
    }
  */

        $res = $this->saveFile($file,$ext);
        if($res['upload_status'] == 1)
        {

          $ins_arr = array(
          'name'          =>  $name,
          'mobile'        =>  $mobile,
          'email'          =>  $email,
          'address'        =>  $address,
          'location'        =>  $location,
          'exp_year'        =>  $exp_years,
          'exp_month'      =>  $exp_months,
          'apply_for'        =>  $apply_for,
          'last_qualification'  =>  $last_qualification,
          'applied_on'  =>  date('Y-m-d'),
          'datetime'  =>  date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
          'resume_file'  => $res['file_path']
              ); 
          $ins_res = $this->db->insert('tbl_new_interview_registration',$ins_arr);

          if($ins_res)
          {
            $senddata['status'] = '1';
            $senddata['message'] = 'Success';
            return json_encode($senddata);
          }else{
            $senddata['status'] = '0';
            $senddata['message'] = 'Error';
            return json_encode($senddata);
          }


        }else{
          $senddata['status'] = 0;
          $senddata['message'] = "Error Uploading File.";
          return json_encode($senddata);
        }

      }else{
        $senddata['status'] = 0;
      $senddata['message'] = "Resume file size should be less than 20 MB .";
      return json_encode($senddata);
      }
    }else{
      $senddata['status'] = 0;
      $senddata['message'] = "Invalid file type. Only PDF,DOC, DOCX, JPG, JPEG and PNG types are accepted.";
      return json_encode($senddata);
    }

  }
```

Comment: If you are uploading some data with POST method don't use "@query". Use "@body" or FormUrlEncoded for that.

Comment: okay using @bodyalso giving the same error and how to use FormUrlEncoded  for uploading file

Comment: `$senddata['status'] = 0;` Is this correct? It's inconsistent with your code written above this line. Probably you want to send `'0'` instead `0`.

Comment: @Ranjan is android code correct?

Comment: You are not getting status here `jsonRootObject.getString( "status" );`. Just debug this line and see the value of `jsonRootObject`.

Comment: okay try to debug it..